# Referring to a file with partially known name in html

Tags: html

I am making a webpage. I have to give link of a log file which is present on the server but that file is generated with a random number at the end.
I know the starting part of the filename. Here is my code -

```
<a href=\"../New_folder/logs/generated.logs/log_parser{*}.log\">Download log file Here</a>
```

for example the name of the file is "log_parser2088.log" this 2088 number is randomly generated everytime the code runs and there is only one file in that folder which starts with the name "log_parser". I want to give reference to this file but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't support this kind of references. Use PHP or ASP.NET for this task since these server side programms have access to the servers file system and can, f.e., read every filename in a directory.

Example for PHP:

```
// path to your log file directory
$directoryPath = "\\home\\logs\\";

// read all files from that directory
$files = scandir($directoryPath);

// print download link
foreach($path in $files)
    echo("<a href=\"" + $path + ">Download</a>");
```